# Runtime path and AIX executables

Tags: linker, aix

I am aware that one can build in a runtime search path into an executable at compile time. I want to understand how to display that path after the executable has been compiled but within the context of AIX!

Looked in Google but not finding answer.

Comment: `dump -X32_64 -H executablename` Details here: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html

Comment: This may or may not be against policy but Lorinczy, thank you, thank you, thank youu!!!!